# FluentValidation Child Validator Message Not Showing

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, .net-4.5, fluentvalidation

I have the following child validator with two constructors one with no parameter and the other passing parent object as parameter:

```
public class ChildValidator : AbstractValidator<Child>
{
    public ChildValidator()
    {
        RuleFor(x => x.LastName)
            .NotEmpty()
            .WithMessage("Last Name is required");
    }

    public ChildValidator(Parent parent)
    {
        RuleFor(x => x.LastName)
            .Equal(x => parent.LastName)
            .WithMessage("Parent and child Last Name must be equal");
    }
}
```

Parent validator:

```
public class ParentValidator : AbstractValidator<Parent>
{
    public ParentValidator()
    {
        RuleFor(x => x.LastName)
            .NotEmpty()
            .WithMessage("Last Name is required");

        RuleFor(x => x.Children)
            .SetCollectionValidator(parent => new ChildValidator(parent));
    }
}
```

Models:

```
[FluentValidation.Attributes.Validator(typeof(ParentValidator))]
public class Parent
{
    public string LastName { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Child> Children { get; set; }
}

[FluentValidation.Attributes.Validator(typeof(ChildValidator))]
public class Child
{
    public string LastName { get; set; }

    public int ParentId { get; set; }
    public virtual Parent Parent { get; set; }
}
```

In Child partial view:

```
@using (Html.BeginCollectionItem("Children"))
{
    @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Id)
    @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.ParentId)

    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.LastName)
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.LastName)
```

The validation works fine. However, while the message for the validator with no parameter is showing, the message for validator with parameter is not.

Comment: How is child related to the parent? One-to-Many?

Comment: @PateeGutee One-to-Many. Question updated.

Comment: Where do you set the Collection Validator?  I know that you say that there is a validator for the Child, but don't you still have to specify in the Parent Validator that the Children use a Collection Validator?

Comment: Can you add the Parent Validator as well?

Comment: @johnny5 Question updated.

Comment: @corix010, are you sure that you aren't getting the proper error message?  Did you check the Full message, by clicking the Magnifying glass,  I think the default Message Aggregator adds new lines so you just aren't viewing the message properly

Comment: @johnny5 not sure where to find the magnifying glass.

Comment: @corix010 its when you are inspectings string property in Visual studio you should be able to view the whole string with the magnifying glass.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem caused by using partial view for children. When you call `@Html.Partial("PartialViewName", model.Children[i])`, you lose Children[i] part of expression. In other words, `ModelState` contains key `"Children[0].LastName"`, when you render validation message for key "LastName".

Most probably you see message for parameterless validator, because clientside validation works here. But for validator with parameter you use custom logic, that works through `ModelState`.

The solution is to move your partial view content to main view, or using editor template instead of partial view: move partial view to /ControllerName/EditorTemplates/ folder and call `@Html.EditorFor(m => m.Children[i], "PartialViewName")`